# SVN Client (stand alone) to auto get stuff from our real SVN

Tags: svn

As a small company we are currently using a Ubuntu server as a NAS device and want to backup our working SVN repository via a SVN client. Does anyone know a good stand-alone SVN client? I've read about rabbitvcs but it's to much in the core. We only need a client which we can apply a time schedule on so it auto fetch files.

PS: We are using Ubuntu desktop and server in the background.

Answer (score 0):

svn from the command line, package name subversion.
You can create a cron job, something like this:

```
*/5 * * * * svn update --username USER --password PASS  /path/to/your/working/copy
```

or

create a script to commit:

```
cd /path/to/your/working/copy
svn commit -m "Cron commit of code"
```

and call that script from a cron job.